# Excel Formula using VB

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to insert a formula in an Excel cell using the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Str3(I) & "47").Formula = "=Count(Str4(I)14:Str4(I)43)"
```

Where `Str4` is string variable. I get a runtime error which means that the string inside the `Count` function it is not interpreted to the desired range. I am trying to figure out how to solve this but I was not able to solve this yet. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `"=Count(" & Str4(I) & "14:" & Str4(I)& "43)"`

Comment: OR `"=COUNT(" & Range(Str4(I) & "14:" & Str4(I)& "43").Address(0,0) & ")"`

Comment: @Scott : Thanks. Worked. So many time wasted...